# Repeatable data content in umbraco

Tags: plugins, umbraco, document, datarepeater

I am just wondering is there any plugin to create dynamic content for a page i.e something similar to a data repeaters in .net. To make it simple it should be a section that should contains 5 to 6 fields/property like

```
heading
heading 2
image
content - rich text editor
info
```

This must be in repeatable control so that the editor can add any number of these section a page and all these should be displayed in a single page.

Is there a plugin for the above functionality or what is the best way to achieve this.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Aneesh

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this without any plugins.

Create your repeatable section (containing the relevant fields) as a document type, and then use the multi-node picker in another document type to select one or many of the sections.

So for example, I could have a FAQs page (which uses a document type called "FAQs Page"), and I want to be able to add multiple question and answers to this page. I could set up a document type called "Question". This will contain two fields: Question and Answer.

On the "FAQs Page" document type, I would add a multi-node picker field called "Questions". This way, an author could select multiple "Question" nodes to appear on the FAQs page.

You would obviously need the code to output this, and also you would create a data type that inherited from multi-node picker, so that you could limit the selection to only Question nodes.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the Repeatable Custom Content datatype which works well but does not support all data types. But it does support all the ones you need for your stated purpose (textstring, media picker, richtext area, etc).

You can find it here: http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/repeatable-custom-content I've used it a few times and it works really well in certain situations (e.g. where the items will not be shared across different pages of your site).

If you are sharing content components across multiple pages then @Digbyswift's solution is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I've always Digbyswifts method, but whilst looking for an alternate solution tonight I found this plugin, which is excellent for those situations where creating lots of widget nodes feels like overkill. It's licensed but the free older version is also available.

http://inaboxdesign.dk/blog/widget-builder-for-umbraco/